# xcode build works on device, but not on simulator

Tags: ios, jenkins, xcode6, ios-simulator, xcodebuild

I want to setup a jenkins server to build our app and run javascript/automation tests on a simulator.

Regarding that topic, I had several issues to launch the app on the simulator. Now I am fighting with the hole simulator thing.

My plan is, to build the app and to launch it on the simulator. Here is what Ive done:

**Step 1:** 
(make archive)

> xcodebuild -project "myApp.xcodeproj" -scheme "api-dev" -configuration "Debug Dev" -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 5s,OS=8.1' archive -archivePath /Users/name/Desktop/build/archive/myApp.xcarchive

**Step 2:**
(make/export .app file)

> xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportFormat app -archivePath /Users/name/Desktop/build/archive/myApp.xcarchive -exportPath /Users/name/Desktop/build/myApp.app

**Step 3:**
(using xcrun to boot simulator)

> xcrun simctl boot < device_id >

**Step 4:**
(using xcrun to install app on booted simulator)

> xcrun simctl install booted /Users/name/Desktop/build/myApp.app

**Step 5:**
(shutdown simulator, since it would crash when I use instruments afterwards)

> xcrun simctl shutdown < device_id >

**Step 6:**
(start .js tests via instruments)

> instruments -w 'iPhone 5s (8.1 Simulator)' -t "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate" /Users/name/Desktop/build/myApp.app -e UIASCRIPT /Users/name/Projects/project-name/myAppTests/UITests/script.js

When I open the simulator to launch the installed App (so without Step 6), only to test if I can open and launch the App, it does not work. Thats my real issue at the moment.

**Error: "Target failed to run: Failed looking up pid of launched process"**

When I open Xcode and take a real device and copy "/Users/name/Desktop/build/myApp.app" on it, it totally works fine...

What do I miss here with the Simulator?
Thank you for your input.

Comment: Hi @thomas_germany, did you figure out what was the problem here?